# Where are the new moderators?

Tags: support, moderators, election

Didn't we have this moderator election during the previous weeks, which should be finished by now?

None of the four candidates has become a moderator until now, and I do not know how to check the state of affairs. What's going on?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/election), looks like Zev and Mariano were elected. I presume there will be a banner installed soon (they probably have to accept the election and fill out some forms about behavior and the like).

Comment: @Theo: Thanks a lot! @new moderators: Congratulations!

Comment: Now it's official: http://math.stackexchange.com/about#moderators

Comment: @new moderators: congratulations!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Congrats to [Mariano and Zev](https://math.stackexchange.com/about#moderators)! (And thanks for Rasmus for asking the question; I've been wondering about it myself. Link stolen from Jonas' comment above.)

And thus I proudly retain my place as the Moderator with the lowest rep `;-)`.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to helping out around the site.